# Optimize Postgres query with conditions

Tags: postgresql

I have a query where I am joining tables and checking if the particular incident has failed a processing with error kode 76,75,10 and checking another condition where i checked if course has only 1 incident.

Is there any way to check if course has only 1 incident then only the 1st condition happens in a single query??

Tried with case --> when but not sure

```
select * from course c where id in(select i.course_id from incident i
 join report r on i.report_id=r.id
 join error e on e.report_id=r.id
 join error_code ek on e.error_code_id=ek.id where errorcode in (76,75,10)) and
     (select count(*) from incident i where i.course_id = c.id) =1
```

Answer (score 0):

If both conditions in `and` are fulfilled, then the single `incident` of `course` must be of errorcode 76,75 or 10. So take all incidents with that errorcodes and return only those courses for which there is just one such incident.

```sql
select * from course c where id in (
  select i.course_id
  from incident i
  join ... -- r,e,ek on obvious conditions
  where errorcode in (76,75,10)
  group by i.course_id
  having count(distinct i.id) = 1
)
```

(I used `distinct` since it isn't clear what kind are the relations `i->r->e->ek` of. If all of them are many to one, then `distinct` isn't necessary, otherwise it must be there to avoid false-duplicate `i.id`s due to joins.)

Comment: not working as expected, i want to check first the count 1 condition and then look for errorcode in 76,75,10

Comment: if course has single incident,then only check for errorcodes

Comment: please provide sample input and expected output